# "Is this answer outdated" how to improve UX

Tags: discussion, user-interface, user-experience

[image]

While I'm not sure if I'm in the right place to post it I'd like to share my thoughts about this new feature on SO and how to improve it:

1. The sentence is a bit confusing. This is a negative question, so I click "yes" if it's outdated and "no" if it's up to date. I think that changing it to "Is this answer up to date" would be more intuitive.
2. It's showing up with this icon under every SO answer. It's attractive as it has an icon and two buttons. Wouldn't it be better to have a flag "outdated"? Or is the goal of this to encourage users to analyze answers in terms of being outdated or not?

Comment: *Is the goal of this to encourage users to analyze answers in terms of being outdated or not?* I think yes.

Comment: Also a lot of people doesn't know what is flagging or How to use it? So simple UX like that will help users (Specially new users).

Comment: Since only 1/1000 views gets shown this currently I've never seen it myself. The "No" selection seems pointless to me unless there is some sort of vote tally tracked. Also seems to be missing a "What does this mean?" link